# How would I store a chunk of vertices

Tags: c++, game-engine, glm-math

Currently in voxel game engine

I'm storing every vertice and texture coord in a std::vector(vertex); //vertex is a struct which contains a glm::vec3 and a glm::vec2

example in Chunk class:

```
for(size_t x = 0; x < chunksize; x++){
   for(size_t y = 0; y < chunksize; y++){
    for(size_t z = 0; z < chunksize; z++){
      if(voxelExist[x][y][z]){
       createMesh(vertices, x,y,z, blah, blah) //checking if the neighboring block exist
      }
     }
   }
```

what I have right now I'm storing each chunk vertices like this
but keep in mind my mChunk is a std::vector(vertex) mChunks

now  in ChunkManager class

```
Chunk newChunk();
newChunk.generate();
mChunks.push_back(newChunk.getMesh())
```

I know could delete/remove a chunk vertices by using the chunk.getMeshes.size();
but is there a better way of managing chunk vertices? I tried std::vector(Chunk) but for whatever reason, visual studio compiler complains when using std::vector::erase(); but it works perfectly fine with my std::vector(vertex)

Error that I recieve when using std::vector::erase for std::vector(Chunk) which is a class that I would push_back

Reproduce
Just create a std::vector(with a class) then use std::vector::erase

message : see reference to function template instantiation'std::_Vector_iteratorstd::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>> std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iteratorstd::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>) noexcept(false)' being compiled

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have an error you should include the full error message and create a [mcve] to demonstrate that error. Since we have no idea what `Chunk` looks like or what the error is  it's very hard to guess what the issue might be.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok I just updated my post again with error message

Comment: That's not the full error and here's an example of it working with a class: https://ideone.com/4IYzBB Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok so I just created an empty project and std::vector::erase worked with a class so I'm not entirely sure how would replicate this error outside my personal project  another error message was  C2280: 'Chunk &Chunk::operator =(const Chunk &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: @RetiredNinja hey it's me again apparently  it was a random variable in my chunk class that was uninitialized const-qualified data